# Jquery Menu creation in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Am having doubt can any one please reply...

am write in .cshtml in the following manner,i got runtime error like this..

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'menu'

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/smothness.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("/resources/demos/style.css")" />

 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#me").menu();
      });
        </script>


 <style>
  .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
  </style>



  <body>
          <ul id="me">
              <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                <ul>
                  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>
            </ul>     
            </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jQuery UI *after* jQuery!

Like all jQuery add-on libraries, jQuery-UI is dependant on jQuery existing first. Just reverse the order:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js")"></script>
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/yT7qV/

I have placed all your pieces into the JSFiddle and it works fine, so I have to assume it is down to your having the script & includes outside of a `body` or `head` tag.

Comment: @Arumugam: It works fine in a fiddle, so may be down to your having the scripts outside of a `body` or `head` tag. Suggest you post your entire page HTML to confirm this is the case.

Comment: can any one please reply me step by step method to create a jquery menu  in mvc please reply me

Comment: @Arumugam: You have all the steps right (except the order of includes), but without your full page I can't confirm if your scripts are in the right place in the HTML. You seem to be missing a `head` tag. The scripts have to be in the `body` or in the `head` otherwise the page is invalid HTML to begin with.